# descargar con php un json generado dinámicamente

Tags: php, json, matriz, descargar

Tengo un código, llamado `generar.php`, que, a partir de una matriz, genera un JSON y lo "ofrece" para descarga, así:

```
<?php
    $matriz = [
        "posA" => "Contenido A",
        "posB" => "Contenido B",
        "posC" => "Contenido C",
        "posD" => [
            "posD1" => "Contenido D1",
            "posD2" => "Contenido D2",
            "posD3" => "Contenido D3",
        ],
    ];

    $json = json_encode($matriz);

    header('Cache-control: private');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream'); 
    header('Content-Length: '.strlen($json));
    header('Content-Disposition: filename=json.json');
    flush();
    print ($json);
?>
```

Necesito escribir un php que se conecte a `generar.php` y sea capaz de obtener el fichero `json.json` que se genera. Una vez obtenido, debe poder recuperar la matriz original con `json_decode()`, pero el problema real es obtener el json directamente con un script php.

Comment: Revisa [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php).

Comment: En este caso no sirve. La función file_get_contents() lee el fichero generar.php, no el json que se crea en generar.php. Lo que hace falta es un código que llame al generador y lea el json resultante.

Comment: ¿Le pusiste http? Algo como `file_get_contents('http://localhost/generar.php')`

Comment: Hola, sí. Es exactamente lo que hice. Y lo que obtuve fue el código de generar.php, no que s ejecutara y me devolviera el json.

Comment: Con esa misma URL en el navegador ¿qué obtienes?

Comment: Si se pone la URL en el navegador, se obtiene el JSON deseado. El script generar.php crea el JSON y lo descarga, pero si se pone como argumento de file_get_contents() se obtiene el codigo fuente de generar.php, que no es lo que se busca.